# Apple Script to select System Preference -> Notifications -> Alert Style

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying an Applescript to change alert type.

I have tried the following code, screen shot attached for reference.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.notifications"
end tell
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.notifications"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell window 1 of process "System Preferences"
    repeat with r in rows of table 1 of scroll area 1
        if name of UI element 1 of r is "NotiNoti" then
            set selected of r to true
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat
    --click checkbox "Badge app icon" of group 1
    click radio button "AXNotificationCenterAlert" of group 1

end tell
```

[image]

What *Key* should be there to select the radio buttons(please provide keys for each of them)?

Comment: Not sure if I get your question right, but I think you just missed the `radio group` part. Like `click radio button "None"/"Banners"/"Alerts" of radio group 1 of group 1`

Comment: thats all it worked @user309603. You may add it as answer...

Answer (score 0):

It worked with this one line of change:

```
click radio button "Alerts" of radio group 1 of group 1
```

If you want to use others then use any of these :

```
"None" or "Banners" or "Alerts"
```